# How to send 301 Moved Permanently response in python?

Tags: python, http, request, response, tcpserver

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: /new-path
```

I've to use this 2 line in Python. And I'm using TCPServer. I couldn't actually any doc online, that's why I'm posting here.

Answer (score 0):

You are using TCPserver, **not** an HTTP server. You could use different frameworks for HTTP servers, there are quite a few, but without one you will not be able to send back HTTP response codes I am afraid.

As far as I know, TCPserver is used to built very low level networkservers to send data across. Python has a built-in http server (not to be used for production use cases). See https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html for more info on that.

I could also recommend looking at something like Flask or Django.